# Cannot install phablet-tools, has no installation candidate

Tags: command-line, package-management

Whenever I run the following command

```
$ sudo apt-get install phablet-tools android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

my terminal shows this

```
$ sudo apt-get install phablet-tools android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package phablet-tools is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  repo

E: Package 'phablet-tools' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your Ubuntu version. `phablet-tool` is [available only for 14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=phablet-tools&searchon=names).

Answer (score 0):

The package was removed from the archive after Canonical dropped support of phones and the unity 8 stack.

If you are on either Ubuntu 14.04 or Ubuntu 16.04, the `phablet-tools` package is in the `universe` repository, so you must make sure it is enabled in *Software Properties* before you'll be able to install it.